# comparing initially created table with its updated form in postgres

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

My main task is to update a column named modifiedDate(that specifies the time when the table was updated) when the table is updated.
So, how can i compare the initally created table and updated table and assign a trigger function in postgreS.

I have no idea about this

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. It will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues. Please explain *compare the initially created table and updated table and assign a trigger*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.